# Bold reserved time with 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm wondering if anyone could help me and I tried to get it to work for couple days. The slots array will list from 17:00 to 21:00, and the reserved array will bold that matches the slots array. Sometimes it just bold one slots list when there are 2 more to bold. Thanks

```
$slots = array('17:00', '18:00','19:00','20:00','21:00');
$reserved =array('17:00', '18:00','19:00');

foreach($slots as  $index =>$value) {
    if($value == $reserved[$index]){
        echo "bold".$value."/bold";
    }else{
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

EXAMPLE:

**17:00**
**18:00**
19:00
20:00
21:00

Comment: https://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: I tried  the in_array and I think you are not understanding what I am trying to do.

Comment: change `if($value == $reserved[$index]) ...` to `if(in_array($value,$reserved)){...`

Comment: Thanks Tim for that quick example and that did it!

Answer (score 0):

Use in_array() function

```
if(in_array($value, $reserved)) {
    echo "bold".$value."/bold";
```